# IA 32 read command line argument

Tags: linux, assembly, command-line, x86

I am trying to read command line arguments with assembly code for IA 32. I found an explanation of how to do it here http://www.paladingrp.com/ia32.shtml. I am able to use the stack pointer to get the number of arguments but I am not able to get the value of the arguments.
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
movl 8(%esp), %edx  # Move pointer to argument 1 to edx
movl (%edx), %ebx   # Move value of edx to ebx
movl $1, %eax       # opcode for exit system call in eax
int $0x80           # return
```

Am I getting the correct pointer? If so, how do I get the value of it? If not, how do I get the correct pointer?

Comment: Read the http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/

Answer (score 2):

> `movl (%edx), %ebx   # Move value of edx to ebx`

That doesn't move value of `EDX` to `EBX` (the comment is incorrect).

That *dereferences* pointer in `EDX`, and puts the result of dereference into `EBX`. So if you invoked your program with `./a.out foo`, then `EBX` will end up being `0x006f6f66 (== '\0oof' ("foo\0" in little-endian))`.

I am guessing that's not what you wanted, but your question is not very clear about what you are expecting to happen where.